# Display view items as thumbnails

Tags: views

I would like to make a view created as a block where every item is displayed as a thumbnail of a cover photo-field of the content type.

I can't find this option in the display options dropdown ... How should I go about it?

Comment: what do you mean by "display options dropdown" ? if you click on the `Content: Image` there is no `thumbnail` option under `Image style`?

Comment: gah! thanks for opening my eyes! I was thinking too short, looking at the first screen of the create view wizard

Answer (score 2):

In Drupal 7, you just need to use **Image style** as answered by Jack-PL

[image]